# for loop in python why does this return 8000 not 9020

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

does anyone know why does this return 8000 and not 9020.. but when I do not indent the return statement, it gives me 9020?

[this is my code]

```py
def over_nine_thousand(lst):
    sum = 0
    for num in lst:
        sum += num
        if sum > 9000:
            break
        return sum
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: as written right now, it returns after the first iteration, but if you don't indent, it iterates over `lst` and reaches `return` when either the `lst` was consumed or `sum` exceeded 9000.

Comment: You have a `return` statement inside the for loop.  Therefore the loop will run only _once_, because `return` causes the function to terminate.  Presumably you intended the `return` to be outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please create fully reproducible example and add it as text, that way you will more likely to receive high quality answer.

```
def func(lst):
    sum = 0
    for num in lst:
        sum+= num
        if(sum>9000):
            break
    return sum
```

you need the return to be inside the func but outside the for.